# How should I make the connection between two models in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a sample project where there are `courses` which are consisted of `lessons` and are thought by `instructors`.

Here are my defined models:

```
    public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }

    }

    public class Lesson
    {
        public enum MediaTypes
        {
            Audio,
            Video,
            Text,
            PDF
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public MediaTypes MediaType { get; set; }
        public string MediaUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class Instructor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }
        public int Rating{ get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my database diagram drawn by Entity Framework Power Tools.
[image: Database Diagram]

I have referred `Instructors` and `Lessons` in `Course` model, So why there are no relations between `Course`, `Lesson` and `Instructor`? What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks so much.

Comment: You have many-to-many relationships here, so there must be an intermediate table to join them together.

Comment: I thought scaffolding would take care of that. How should I achieve that? Do I need to add something in Models?

Comment: It probably is taken care of but you haven't added those intermediate tables to your diagram.

Comment: By the way, I imagine a lesson only links to a single course, not a collection of them.

Comment: David G is correct.  A mapping table should be created.  Once that is done, if you create foreign keys on the tables in SQL and re-import the tables then the links will be created in code automatically.  If you are doing code first (which is what is recommended since newer versions of EF will only support this method), then you will need to set them up appropriately.  This link should have what you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application